# Gremlin function doesn't exist in Javascript, but works in console

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm having trouble transitioning from the console to Javascript. Starting with one Vertex:

`g.addV('airport').property('code','AUS').as('aus')`

I want to add another airport and then add routes between the two. In the Gremlin console, this works:

`g.V().has("airport","code","AUS").as("aus").addV("airport").property("code","ZZZ").as("zzz").addE("route").from("aus").to("zzz")`


`g.V().has("airport", "code", "AUS").out("route").has("airport", "code", "ZZZ").hasNext()
==>true`

But, if I try the same process in my Lambda Javascript, the traversal fails:

`g.V()
      .has('airport', 'code', 'AUS')
      .as('aus')
      .addV('airport')
      .property('code', 'QQQ')
      .as('qqq')
      .addE('route')
      .from('aus')
      .to('qqq')
      .next();`


`{"errorMessage":"error updating event: TypeError: g.V(...).has(...).as(...).addV(...).property(...).as(...).addE(...).from is not a function"}`

Is there an implementation detail I'm missing between the console and JS? I'm using AWS Neptune and `"gremlin": "^3.2.9"`.

Comment: Try using gremlin 3.3.3 from npm

Comment: Yes, the undocumented `from_` syntax works.